# Double delimiters in listings

Tags: listings, verbatim

Using the `listings` package, one can define a format for some arbitrary set of delimiters and the characters enclosed within. However, when using double delimiters, the specified format doesn't apply to the closing delimiter.

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    moredelim = [s][\color{blue}]{`}{'},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
macros u i
`u`i''
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This code yields the following output:
[image]

Notice how the last closing delimiter `'` is not formatted in blue. Is there a way to fix this?

*Note*: I used the `upquote` package to get the desired look of verbatim apostrophes, but if not used the problem persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a nesting issue. From the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (page 24), you can add an asterisk to allow inner delimiters to be found:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    moredelim = *[s][\color{blue}]{`}{'},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
macros u i
`u`i''
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]